# How to assign a particular driver to a device in linux?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers

I am using [TP LINK TL-WN822N](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN822N_v1) wireless device which has two chips. It works with [Carl9170](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/carl9170), however I would like to use [ath9k](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k/#Available_devices) which according to the link supports AR9102 which is one of the chips. I tried the following command to disable to Carl9170 driver my NIC was using

```
modprobe -r carl9170
```

My device is disabled now. I used the following to load ath9k.

```
modprobe ath9k
```

When I check for loaded modules using `lsmod`, I see ath9k is loaded

[image]

My device is still disabled. I can't see it after giving the commands `ifconfig` or `iwconfig`. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *ath9k which according to the link supports AR9102 which is one of the chips*

Short answer: The **AR9170** is the chip that counts, and `ath9k` does not support it; the AR9102 is basically a "dumb radio" (See diagram from Atheros below.)

[image]

Long answer: Your device uses two chips for a reason; the AR9102 is the *RF chip*; it's relatively "dumb", in that all it does is convert the zeros and ones input into it to the proper radio-frequency signals (2.4 GHz, multiple channels) and transmits them out via the antenna (it does the same in reverse for received data). As such, it probably doesn't need a software driver.

The AR9170 or "CPU" is the real heart of the device, which talks to the software on one side and the AR9102 on the other. It knows about 802.11 abgn standards, wireless access points, encryption, etc.; **the AR9102 does not.**

Hence, you can't use `ath9k` because it does not support the AR9170 -- the one chip of the two that really matters for your purposes.

Comment: [This](http://www.wikidevi.com/files/Atheros/specsheets/AR9001U.pdf) document has a good picture to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you both for excellent information! That clears things up.